# Better approach to listen hundreds of Kafka Topic and store data into Database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

We are building system to migrate data from Sybase to Oracle using Product called Qlik, it Provides CDC as well

So here is my scenario

> - Qlik Tool will create Kafka Topic for each table and publish all data from sybase DB
> - Each message in Topic has some meta data, and one of them will tell us whether its INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
> - On other hand we have to build consumer layer to pull data from each topic and update/sync up respective tables in Oracle DB

I wounder that what would be the better approach to build consumer layer. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, you need a consumer, and schema inference to store fields in a table.

Kafka Connect JDBC Sink can be made to work and scales well, but "better" is relative, depending on your expected results.

Comment: We have decent amount of transformation, otherwise kafka-connect would be our preference.

Can we have Java Client to listen for multiple topics? Is it good approach?

Comment: If you have transformations, then you can use ksqldb or Kafka Streams prior to the  Connect sink